# ORA-00937: Sum inside a case inside a sum that is inside another case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns the total of a movimentation:

```
SELECT 
    CASE PROD_TYPE
         WHEN 1 THEN SUM(WEIGHT)
         WHEN 2 THEN SUM(CASE MOVIMENT
                           1 THEN SUM(QUANTITY)
                           2 THEN SUM(QUANTITY * -1)
                        END)
    END AS TOTAL
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PROD_TYPE, MOVIMENT
```

This query in giving me the error ORA-00937, if a remove the last sum doesnt give the error but the result is not the right one:

```
WHEN 2 THEN CASE MOVIMENT
                1 THEN SUM(QUANTITY)
                2 THEN SUM(QUANTITY * -1)
            END
```

edit1:
I have the following data
PROD_TYPE |  QUANTITY  |  WEIGHT  |  MOVIMENT

--------2------------1100-------------0-------------1---
--------2------------1000-------------0-------------1---
--------2------------1200-------------0-------------1---
--------2------------1200-------------0-------------2---
*1 is input, 2 output
The right result is 2100, but if I remove the last sum it will give two results: 3300 and -1200 
I tried to put the QUANTITY in the group by clause but I kept getting the same error.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The right output is 2100 (1100 + 1000 + 1200 - 1200  )

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE PROD_TYPE
         WHEN 1 THEN SUM(WEIGHT)
         WHEN 2 THEN SUM(CASE MOVIMENT
                           WHEN 1 THEN QUANTITY
                           WHEN 2 THEN - QUANTITY
                         END)
        END) AS TOTAL
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PROD_TYPE, MOVIMENT;
```

Comment: I tried but the result it was two values without summing them